# Advice for Retail Sales Program

Tags: c++

I need help with setting up `int ProductNumber[]`, `int ProductQuantity` and `double RetailValue[]`. I'm not sure how I should initialize these.

> An online retailer sells five products whose retail prices are as follows:
>   Product 1, $2.98
>   Product 2, $4.50
>   Product 3, $3.98
>   Product 4, $4.49
>   Product 5, $6.87

```
#include "RetailSales.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

RetailSales::RetailSales()
{

}

void RetailSales::enterProducts()
{
int productNumber[] =
int ProductQuantity[] =
double RetailValue[] =

}

void RetailSales::displayTotalValue()
{

}
```

Header File

---

```
/*
* CSIS1600
* A04a Retail Sales
* class RetailSales header file
*/

#ifndef RETAILSALES_H
#define RETAILSALES_H

class RetailSales
{
public:
RetailSales();
void enterProducts();
void displayTotalValue();

private:
double productPrice[6];
double productTotal[6];
int productQuantity[6];
double totalRetailValue;
};

#endif // RETAILSALES_H
```

How can I set up my arrays to contain the numbers above?

Comment: It appears you only need help with initialising the values in the arrays mentioned. Is that correct? It would be worthwhile clarifying your question to just ask that (rather than dumping your entire assignment text which seemed to not relate to the question). I have [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9816704) to (hopefully) improve what you were asking

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not mentioning ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)!

For a container where you know its size and elements straight away (like the product prices), it's easy to construct your `vector` as follows:

```
const std::vector<float> retailValue = { 2.98f, 4.5f, 3.98f, 4.49f, 6.87f };
```

`retailValue` now contains 5 values and cannot be modified.

For a container where you don't know the values to begin with (e.g. you require user input) you can just start with an empty `vector` and populate it once you know the values:

```
// Empty container to store values
std::vector<int> productNumbers;
// For each product price, get a corresponding product number
for (auto n = 0; n < retailValue.size(); ++n)
{
    auto productNumber = 0;
    // Get a value from the console
    std::cin >> productNumber;
    // don't forget to handle errors from std::cin
    ...
    // Add this product number to the container
    productNumbers.push_back(productNumber)
}
```

## If you are unable to use `std::vector`

You can mostly do the same thing with a simple array, with the key difference you can't have an *empty* array. You will need to know how many elements you require to begin with, unlike `std::vector` which can grow dynamically

```
const int numberOfProducts = 5;
// Array of numbers that can't change.
const float retailValue[] = { 2.98f, 4.5f, 3.98f, 4.49f, 6.87f };
int productNumbers[numberOfProducts] = {};
// For each product that has a price, obtain a product number from the console
for (auto n = 0; n < numberOfProducts; ++n)
{
    auto productNumber = 0;
    // Get a value from the console
    std::cin >> productNumber;
    // don't forget to handle errors from std::cin
    ...
    // Add this product number to the container
    productNumbers[n] = productNumber;
}
```

Comment: I can only use arrays and not vectors for this assignment. :(

Comment: Thanks. That Helped alot.